# How to load more than 255 chars data in Text Area as seperate line

Tags: soql, api, data-loader, data, mulesoft

How to load more than 255 chars data in Text Area as seperate line when pushing data from Mule soft is there any line break can we add

Answer (score 3):

In a `Text Area` field you can't load more than 255 chars, but those characters can be displayed on multiple lines.
[Custom Filed Types Documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.custom_field_types.htm&type=5):

> Text Area
> **Allows users to enter up to 255 characters** that display on separate lines

It doesn't mean that you are allowed to have multiple lines each one filled with up to 255 characters.

Please note that whitespaces and line break are counted against this limit, so if you have 100 charaters on the first two lines and 50 characters on third line, you're allowed to put at most two characted on the fourth line.

You need a `Text Area (Long)` field which supports up to 131,072 characters and allow line break `\n`.

Comment: Its fine if its displayed in multiple lines but How to push that data is my question.

Comment: @Somesh there is no way to load more than 255 chars in a Text Area field. Please also note that spaces and line break are counted against that limit. So if you have 100 characters on the first two lines and 50 chars on the third one, you can have at most 2 chars on the fourth line

Comment: @RuvebDG then in Data Type of Text Area its metioned allows user to eneter 255 chars in seperate line , So it meaning not each line 255 chars right?

Comment: @Somesh it means that the maximum number of characters is 255, no matter on how many lines you put them. The documentation is very clear about it. It doesn't mean that you can put 255 on each line multiple times. If you have 255 chars on a single line, you are not allowed to have a second line.